# Google Sheets help: SUMIF from DropDown

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

I have a dropdown menu if Yes/No. I need to add the values corresponding to the cell if Y is selected

[image]

Comment: Putting up the link here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cBNa9MjcfBVdTollPIUUtZdcwekPvBW6bG6N8LHdLrs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5):

Could also use `=SumIf(C:C,"Y",D:D)` Essentially this just goes down Column C (your Y/N value) and if the value is Y it knows to add the value in the corresponding cell from Column D to the sum. Otherwise, it skips it.

Answer (score 1):

try simple:

```
=SUM(FILTER(D:D, C:C="Y"))
```